# How can reduce the time of this SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

Can someone tell me how can I reduce the number of time using this query?

This is the SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    `i`.`id`, 
    `i`.`local_file`, 
    `i`.`remote_file`, 
    `i`.`remote_file_big`, 
    `i`.`image_name`, 
    `i`.`description`,
     IF(`i`.`prevent_sync`='1', '5', `i`.`status`) `status`,
     GROUP_CONCAT(`il`.`user_id` SEPARATOR ',') AS `likes`,
     COUNT(`il`.`user_id`) AS `likes_count`
FROM `images` `i`
LEFT JOIN `image_likes` `il` ON (`il`.`image_id`=`i`.`id`) 
WHERE 1 AND `i`.`created` < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR) 
GROUP BY `i`.`id` 
ORDER BY `likes_count` DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0;
```

On checking the query time, this is the result:

```
# Query_time: 9.948511  Lock_time: 0.000181  Rows_sent: 3  Rows_examined: 4730490
# Rows_affected: 0
```

Table `image_likes`:

```
id (Primary)    int(11)
local_file  varchar(100)
orig_name   varchar(100)
remote_file varchar(1000)
remote_file_big varchar(1000)
remote_page varchar(1000)   
image_name  varchar(50)
image_name_eng  varchar(50)
user_idIndex    int(11)
author  varchar(50)
credit  varchar(250)
credit_eng  varchar(250)
location    varchar(50)
description varchar(500)
description_eng varchar(275)
notes   varchar(550)
categoryIndex   int(11)
date_range  varchar(50)
createdIndex    datetime
license enum('1', '2', '3')
status  enum('0', '1', '2', '3', '4')
locked  enum('0', '1')
watch_list  enum('0', '1', '2')
url_title   varchar(100)
url_data    varchar(8192)
rem_date        datetime
rem_notes   varchar(500)
original_url    varchar(1000)
prevent_sync    enum('0', '1')
checked_by  int(11)
system_recommended  enum('0', '1')
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Do you have any index? You should add index on `created`

Comment: Post your table structure and the indexes you put in.

Comment: As well as listing your table structures and indexes; post an EXPLAIN of the query to show how it's being executed

Comment: Do "SHOW CREATE TABLE image_likes;" and post the result here. It's important to see, whether it has an index on `image_id` field.

Comment: "WHERE 1 AND" - what is this? There is no need for 1.

Comment: This shouldn't even work... if you group by one column, you have to group by the rest of them, unless those other columns are aliases to aggregates...

Comment: @Brad - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html

Comment: When there are ties, e.g. four images having the maximum count, then your limit clause chooses three of them arbitrarily. Is this on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex task for the DB, and there is not much you can do to get the result really efficiently. You can try to limit the IO with a subquery that operates on covering indexes. Remove everything from your query that you don't need to get the three image ids:

```
SELECT i.id
FROM images i
JOIN image_likes il ON il.image_id = i.id
WHERE i.created < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
GROUP BY i.id
ORDER BY COUNT(il.image_id) DESC
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0
```

The smallest covering indexes would be `images(created, id)` and `image_likes(image_id)`. With 5M likes, both indexes together will consume something like 100 - 200 MB and should easily fit into memory. The size of the temporary table, that has to be sorted by the count, will also be smaller.

Use that query as derived table (subquery in FROM clause) and join only the three rows from the `images` table:

```
SELECT
    `i`.`id`, 
    `i`.`local_file`, 
    `i`.`remote_file`, 
    `i`.`remote_file_big`, 
    `i`.`image_name`, 
    `i`.`description`,
     IF(`i`.`prevent_sync`='1', '5', `i`.`status`) `status`,
     GROUP_CONCAT(`il`.`user_id` SEPARATOR ',') AS `likes`,
     COUNT(`il`.`user_id`) AS `likes_count`
FROM (
    SELECT i.id
    FROM images i
    JOIN image_likes il ON il.image_id = i.id
    WHERE i.created < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
    GROUP BY i.id
    ORDER BY COUNT(il.image_id) DESC
    LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0
) sub
JOIN images i ON i.id = sub.id
JOIN image_likes il ON il.image_id = i.id
GROUP BY i.id
ORDER BY likes_count;
```

If that isn't fast enough, you should cache the `likes_count` using triggers.

Answer (score 0):

This probably suffers from the "inflate-deflate" syndrome which often happens with `JOIN` + `GROUP BY`.  Also it usually leads to incorrect aggregate values.

```
SELECT  `id`, `local_file`, `remote_file`,
        `remote_file_big`, `image_name`, `description`,
        IF(`prevent_sync`='1', '5', `status`) `status`,
        s.likes, s.likes_count
    FROM  `images` AS `i`
    JOIN  
        ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(user_id SEPARATOR ',') AS likes,
                  COUNT(*) AS likes_count
              FROM     `image_likes`
              GROUP BY  image_id 
              ORDER BY  `likes_count` DESC
              LIMIT  3 OFFSET 0;
        ) AS s  ON s.`image_id`=`i`.`id`
    WHERE  `created` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
    ORDER BY  `likes_count` DESC;
```

This variant will exclude rows with likes_count=0, but that seems reasonable.

It assumes that the `PRIMARY KEY` of `images` is `id`.

`image_likes` needs `INDEX(user_id)` and will make one scan of that table.  Then only 3 lookups into `images`.

The original query had to scan all the rows of `images` and repeatedly scan all of `image_likes`.